# Does anyone use Mahapps dialogs in try/catch operator?

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, messagebox, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to use Mahapps dialogs instead of default WPF Message Box.

This way I used MessageBox in WinForms and in default WPF.

```
 try
        {
            // do something    
        }

 catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Attention!");

        }
```

My question is how do I use similar way for Mahapps dialogs?
Need an example.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar scenario where I wanted unique messagebox's.  Here's the sample code

```
<Grid x:Name="Popup" Visibility="Visible" MouseDown="Popup_MouseDown">
        <Grid Background="Black" Opacity="0.5"/>
        <Border
        MinWidth="250" 
        BorderBrush="Black" 
        BorderThickness="12,6" 
        CornerRadius="200,0,200,100" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="90,40,102,44" Height="235" Width="325" Background="White">
        </Border>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtMessage" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="176,106,194,117"><InlineUIContainer>
            </InlineUIContainer></TextBlock>
        <Button x:Name="btnOK" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="176,202,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40"/>
    </Grid>
```

You get the same results, just make sure you put the XAML at the end.  For the C# part its

```
 try
    {
        // do something    
    }

 catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Popup.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
       txtMessage.Text = "Attention!!!";
    }
```

The MouseDown event is so it goes away if clicked off the "Message Box"

Comment: Thank you! I will try that code.That's the point if it is going to work with the system exceptions like ex.